# electron Build windows not getting full screen (workAreaSize,workArea,maximize) not working

Tags: angular, electron, electron-builder

I'm using angular 6 with an electron. when I'm compiling the windows build the build not getting full screen. I'm changing the method in main.ts is workarea, WorkAreaSize etc[image] not it's also not working.

```
const electronScreen = screen;
const size = electronScreen.getPrimaryDisplay().workAreaSize;
console.log(size);
win = new BrowserWindow({
x: 0,
y: 0,
width: size.width,
height: size.height,

icon: __dirname + '/icon.ico',
resizable:false,
webPreferences: {
 nodeIntegration:true,
 webSecurity: false,
 plugins: true
 },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[Suggestion here:](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/16263#issuecomment-453454185)

> I have notice that if I do not use resizable:false, it works as expected, and surprisingly it is nevertheless unresizable.